# Eclipse Egit : Label decorations does not show and option does not remain checked

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Without any apparent reason (no update whatsoever), since a few days the EGit text decoration doesn't show up in Eclipse any more.
It is unchecked in "Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations > Git", and I cannot check it!! If I check it and "Apply" and "OK", nothing happens and it remains unchecked...

My Eclipse log goes like :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-04-05 14:18:08.926
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RevWalkException: Walk failure.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.iterator(RevWalk.java:1237)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalkUtils.find(RevWalkUtils.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalkUtils.count(RevWalkUtils.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BranchTrackingStatus.of(BranchTrackingStatus.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratableResourceHelper.getBranchStatus(DecoratableResourceHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratableResourceAdapter.<init>(DecoratableResourceAdapter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.GitLightweightDecorator.decorateResource(GitLightweightDecorator.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.GitLightweightDecorator.decorate(GitLightweightDecorator.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing commit 11d64b0d91bf24bfb551fbf20c3f6b244dacd74a
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.getCachedBytes(RevWalk.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit.parseHeaders(RevCommit.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.PendingGenerator.next(PendingGenerator.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.DelayRevQueue.next(DelayRevQueue.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.FixUninterestingGenerator.next(FixUninterestingGenerator.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.StartGenerator.next(StartGenerator.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.next(RevWalk.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.iterator(RevWalk.java:1235)
    ... 15 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-04-05 14:18:08.927
!MESSAGE Exception in Decorator. The 'Git' decorator will be disabled.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-04-05 14:18:08.927
!MESSAGE Walk failure.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing commit 11d64b0d91bf24bfb551fbf20c3f6b244dacd74a
    at org.eclipse.jgit.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.getCachedBytes(RevWalk.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit.parseHeaders(RevCommit.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.PendingGenerator.next(PendingGenerator.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.DelayRevQueue.next(DelayRevQueue.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.FixUninterestingGenerator.next(FixUninterestingGenerator.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.StartGenerator.next(StartGenerator.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.next(RevWalk.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.iterator(RevWalk.java:1235)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalkUtils.find(RevWalkUtils.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalkUtils.count(RevWalkUtils.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BranchTrackingStatus.of(BranchTrackingStatus.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratableResourceHelper.getBranchStatus(DecoratableResourceHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.DecoratableResourceAdapter.<init>(DecoratableResourceAdapter.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.GitLightweightDecorator.decorateResource(GitLightweightDecorator.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.decorators.GitLightweightDecorator.decorate(GitLightweightDecorator.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

My conf :

```
Eclipse Platform
Version: 4.2.2
Build id: M20130204-1200

Eclipse Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Index Frameworks
Version: 4.0.0.201206120848

Eclipse EGit
Version: 2.2.0.201212191850-r
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-installing Eclipse and cleaning my workspace. Now everything is fine...

Answer (score 1):

According to the stack trace, it seems to choke because of

```
Missing commit 11d64b0d91bf24bfb551fbf20c3f6b244dacd74a
```

You might want to reset (hard) your repository to origin/master, or to clone it again from an upstream repository, assuming that this is a local problem of your repository only, which might vanish by "replacing" it with the upstream content.